# Sign in with Apple /consent return 400

Tags: apple-developer, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to setup "sign in with Apple" on my webapp, I did the following in developer portal:

1. create primary app id
2. create service id
3. create key

Once I construct the redirect URL to apple authorization page, and login with my apple account, the `/consent` endpoint returns the following HTTP error:

```
code: "-310003"
message: "Sign in with Apple isn't allowed for the app."
suppressDismissal: false
```

I couldn't find anything related to this error code. I did not have a published app in the AppStore, could that be the reason my app is not allowed for sign in with apple?

URL to reproduce the error: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&client_id=com.test.sid&redirect_uri=https://google.com/test&state=123&scope=name%20email&use_popup=true

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to my organization Apple account. If I switch to login with my personal Apple account the flow does work.

Didn't find any documentation about organization account cannot use "sign in with Apple" feature tho.